# How to use JavaScript to apply slidedown functionality in accordion?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In this snippet below, I'm trying to apply a slide down functionality to each panel when opened. The result is that slide down is working.

The problem is...

1. In mobile, when a second panel is opened, the first panel remains at full height.
2. Slide up functionality isn't working as expected.

Lastly, I have hundreds of these accordions on my site. I need to be able to update the JS/CSS accordingly, without changing the HTML markup.

**How do I apply JavaScript slide up/down functionality to accordion panels when opened?**

```js
function initAccordion() {
  let handlePanelClick = (e) => {
    showPanel(e.currentTarget.parentNode);
  };

  function showPanel(panel) {
    let isWide = isWideScreen();
    let isActive = panel.classList.contains("active");

    if (!isActive) {
      panel.classList.add("active");
      panel.style.height = "auto";

      var height = panel.clientHeight + "px";

      panel.style.height = "0px";

      setTimeout(() => {
        panel.style.height = height
      }, 0);
    } else {
      panel.style.height = "auto";

      panel.addEventListener(
        "transitionend",
        () => {
          panel.classList.remove("active");
        }, {
          once: true
        }
      );
    }

    if (isWide) {
      if (!isActive) {
        panel.classList.add("active");
      } else {
        panel.classList.remove("active");
      }
    } else {
      // handle mobiles
      let panels = document.querySelectorAll(".panel");
      panels.forEach((p) => p.classList.remove("active"));
      if (!isActive) {
        // open the panel
        panel.classList.add("active");
      }
    }
  }

  let allPanelElements = document.querySelectorAll(".panel");
  allPanelElements.forEach((allPanels) =>
    allPanels
    .querySelector(".acc-trigger")
    .addEventListener("click", handlePanelClick)
  );
}

let isWideScreen = () => {
  return window.matchMedia("(min-width: 992px)").matches;
};
initAccordion(document.getElementsByClassName("accordion"));
```

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 50px auto 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.wrapper a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.wrapper button {
  border-style: none;
  background: white;
}
.wrapper button::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
}
.wrapper .accordion:first-child {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel {
  min-height: unset;
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000A70;
  transition: height 1s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-trigger {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: 0 0;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-trigger .acc-title {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  outline: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-trigger .acc-title:hover svg.acc-icon path {
  fill: #005fec;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-trigger .acc-title h4 {
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #000A70;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  outline: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-trigger .acc-title h4:hover {
  color: #005fec;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-trigger .acc-title svg.acc-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: none;
  margin-left: auto;
  z-index: 3;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-body {
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: height 1s ease-out, opacity 1s ease-out;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-body ol.custom-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-margin-before: 0;
  margin-block-start: 0;
  -webkit-margin-after: 0;
  margin-block-end: 0;
  counter-reset: my-awesome-counter;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-body ol.custom-list li {
  counter-increment: my-awesome-counter;
  padding-left: 1.125rem;
  margin: 2rem 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  color: #000A70;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-body ol.custom-list li::before {
  content: counter(my-awesome-counter) ". ";
  color: #005fec;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-body ol.custom-list li:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-body ol.custom-list li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-body ol.custom-list li a {
  color: #005fec;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-body ol.custom-list li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  -webkit-text-decoration-color: #005fec;
          text-decoration-color: #005fec;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-body ul.custom-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-margin-before: 0;
  margin-block-start: 0;
  -webkit-margin-after: 0;
  margin-block-end: 0;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-body ul.custom-list li {
  background-image: url(/assets/svg/bullet.svg);
  background-position: 0 0.5rem;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-left: 1.125rem;
  margin: 2rem 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-body ul.custom-list li a {
  color: #005fec;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-body ul.custom-list li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  -webkit-text-decoration-color: #005fec;
          text-decoration-color: #005fec;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-body ul.custom-list li:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-body ul.custom-list li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel + .panel {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel.active .acc-body {
  opacity: 1;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  visibility: visible;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel.active .acc-body p {
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel.active .acc-body p + .embed-youtube {
  margin: 1rem 0;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel.active .acc-body p a {
  color: #005fec;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel.active .acc-body p a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  -webkit-text-decoration-color: #005fec;
          text-decoration-color: #005fec;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel.active .acc-icon {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel.active .acc-trigger .acc-title {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel.active p:last-child {
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.acc-title svg.acc-icon {
  transition: all 1s ease;
  min-width: 1rem;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .wrapper {
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  .accordion {
    flex: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="questions">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-start">
      <h3>Any Questions?</h3>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="accordion">
          <div class="panel">
            <button class="acc-trigger">
                <span class="acc-title">
                  <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h4>
                  <svg class="acc-icon" width="16" height="11" viewBox="0 0 16 11" fill="none"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path d="M0 2.82813L2 0.828126L8 6.82813L14 0.828126L16 2.82813L8 10.8281L0 2.82813Z"
                      fill="#000A70" />
                  </svg>
                </span>
              </button>
            <div class="acc-body">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi enim quas laboriosam itaque harum ab voluptas? Deserunt aliquam pariatur voluptatem odit iure autem eos totam eius consequuntur animi. Omnis, ipsam.</p>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi enim quas laboriosam itaque harum ab voluptas? Deserunt aliquam pariatur voluptatem odit iure autem eos totam eius consequuntur animi. Omnis, ipsam.</p>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi enim quas laboriosam itaque harum ab voluptas? Deserunt aliquam pariatur voluptatem odit iure autem eos totam eius consequuntur animi. Omnis, ipsam.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel">
            <button class="acc-trigger">
                <span class="acc-title">
                  <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h4>
                  <svg class="acc-icon" width="16" height="11" viewBox="0 0 16 11" fill="none"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path d="M0 2.82813L2 0.828126L8 6.82813L14 0.828126L16 2.82813L8 10.8281L0 2.82813Z"
                      fill="#000A70" />
                  </svg>
                </span>
              </button>
            <div class="acc-body">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi enim quas laboriosam itaque harum ab voluptas? Deserunt aliquam pariatur voluptatem odit iure autem eos totam eius consequuntur animi. Omnis, ipsam.</p>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi enim quas laboriosam itaque harum ab voluptas? Deserunt aliquam pariatur voluptatem odit iure autem eos totam eius consequuntur animi. Omnis, ipsam.</p>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi enim quas laboriosam itaque harum ab voluptas? Deserunt aliquam pariatur voluptatem odit iure autem eos totam eius consequuntur animi. Omnis, ipsam.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: The animation on `height` property doesn't work with CSS, instead you can use `max-height` property between 0 (means hidden) to 100% (means visible). CSS transition will work when you use `max-height`. You will also need to apply `overflow: hidden;` so when `max-height` is 0, it doesn't show overflowing content.

Comment: @NikLakhani Can you put your suggestion into an answer. I have various heights at play and I'm not entirely sure which heights your referencing.

Comment: why not use jquery ui accordion? https://jqueryui.com/accordion/#collapsible

Comment: @yigitt I am trying to move away from 3rd party libraries. jQuery specifically is still popular, but vanilla JS DOM manipulation has come so far, it's just not necessary.

Comment: @Millhorn I get it and  I agree.  You can check this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you **can't transition/animate between height:0px and auto** you might try this approach:

We're hiding all accordion contents on load in a way that still allows us to calculate their individual heights by js.

```
.acc-body {
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
}
```

We can now store these height values as a data-attribute added to each accordion body.
When a accordion section gets expanded, this height value is applied as a **max-height** inline-style.

#### Example 1: Accordion

```js
// get acc heights
let accordionContents = document.querySelectorAll('.acc-body');
getAccordionHeights(accordionContents);

function getAccordionHeights(accordionContents) {
  accordionContents.forEach(function(acc, i) {
    // reset heights on resize
    if (acc.classList.contains('acc-body-init')) {
      acc.removeAttribute('style');
      acc.classList.remove('acc-body-init');
      console.log('acc heights recalculated')
    }
    let bb = acc.getBoundingClientRect();
    let h = bb.height;
    acc.setAttribute('data-height', (h * 1.5) + 'px');
    acc.classList.add('acc-body-init');
  })
}

// add click event handlers
let accTriggers = document.querySelectorAll('.acc-trigger');
accTriggers.forEach(function(btn, i) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    let panel = e.currentTarget.closest('.panel');
    let btn = panel.querySelector('.acc-trigger');
    let acc = panel.querySelector('.acc-body');
    let accHeight = acc.getAttribute('data-height');
    let opened = document.querySelectorAll('.active');
    // toggle this btn state
    panel.classList.toggle('active');
    // apply max-height from data-attribute
    if (panel.classList.contains('active')) {
      acc.style.maxHeight = accHeight;
      btn.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'true');
      acc.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'false');
    } else {
      acc.style.maxHeight = '0px';
      btn.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
      acc.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');
    }
    if (!isWideScreen()) {
      closeOpened(opened)
    }

  })
});

// add close all previously opened
function closeOpened(opened) {
  opened.forEach(function(panel, i) {
    let acc = panel.querySelector('.acc-body');
    let btn = panel.querySelector('.acc-trigger');
    panel.classList.remove('active');
    acc.style.maxHeight = '0px';
    btn.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
    acc.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');
  });
}

let isWideScreen = () => {
  return window.matchMedia("(min-width: 992px)").matches;
};

// recalculate heights on window resize
window.onresize = function(e) {
  let opened = document.querySelectorAll('.active');
  getAccordionHeights(accordionContents);
  closeOpened(opened)
}
```

```css
.acc-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1em;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 50px auto 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.wrapper a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.wrapper button {
  border-style: none;
  background: white;
}

.wrapper button::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
}

.wrapper .accordion:first-child {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.panel {
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000A70;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.acc-trigger {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  outline: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: 0 0;
  padding: 1em 0;
}

.acc-icon {
  color: inherit;
  pointer-events: none;
  margin-left: auto;
  z-index: 3;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  align-self: flex-start;
  padding: 0.5em 0;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.acc-trigger h4 {
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.acc-trigger:focus,
.acc-trigger:hover {
  color: #005fec;
}


/*** hidden acc body before initialisation to get heights */

.acc-body {
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  visibility: hidden;
  clip: rect(0px auto 2px 0px);
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
}

.acc-body-init {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0px;
  clip: unset;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

.active .acc-body-init {
  max-height: 500px;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  visibility: visible;
}

.acc-body p a {
  color: #005fec;
}

.acc-body p a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  -webkit-text-decoration-color: #005fec;
  text-decoration-color: #005fec;
}

.active .acc-icon {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.active .acc-trigger {
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}

.panel p:last-child {
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .wrapper {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .accordion {
    flex: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg style="display:none" class="acc-icon" width="16" height="11" viewBox="0 0 16 11" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <symbol id="btn-acc" viewBox="0 0 16 11">
        <path d="M0 2.82813L2 0.828126L8 6.82813L14 0.828126L16 2.82813L8 10.8281L0 2.82813Z" fill="currentColor" />
    </symbol>
</svg>

<section id="questions">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="accordion">
      <div class="panel">
        <button class="acc-trigger" aria-expanded="false" id="accBtn01">
                        <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h4>
                        <svg class="acc-icon" viewBox="0 0 16 11"  >
                          <use href="#btn-acc"/>
                        </svg>
                    </button>
        <div class="acc-body" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="accBtn01">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="#">consectetur</a> adipisicing elit. Animi enim quas laboriosam itaque harum ab voluptas? Deserunt aliquam pariatur voluptatem odit iure autem eos totam eius consequuntur animi. Omnis, ipsam.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi enim quas laboriosam itaque harum ab voluptas? Deserunt aliquam pariatur voluptatem odit iure autem eos totam eius consequuntur animi. Omnis, ipsam.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi enim quas laboriosam itaque harum ab voluptas? Deserunt aliquam pariatur voluptatem odit iure autem eos totam eius consequuntur animi. Omnis, ipsam.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi enim quas laboriosam itaque harum ab voluptas? Deserunt aliquam pariatur voluptatem odit iure autem eos totam eius consequuntur animi. Omnis, ipsam.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel">
        <button class="acc-trigger" aria-expanded="false" id="accBtn02">
                        <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. <br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </h4>
                        <svg class="acc-icon" viewBox="0 0 16 11" >
                            <use href="#btn-acc"/>
                          </svg>
                    </button>
        <div class="acc-body" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="accBtn02">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi enim quas laboriosam itaque harum ab voluptas? Deserunt aliquam pariatur voluptatem odit iure autem eos totam eius consequuntur animi. Omnis, ipsam.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi enim quas laboriosam itaque harum ab voluptas? Deserunt aliquam pariatur voluptatem odit iure autem eos totam eius consequuntur animi. Omnis, ipsam.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi enim quas laboriosam itaque harum ab voluptas? Deserunt aliquam pariatur voluptatem odit iure autem eos totam eius consequuntur animi. Omnis, ipsam.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

You might also need a window resize event handler to recalculate heights, when the window resizing occurs.

I also strongly recommend to add appropriate **aria-attributes** for better [accessibility.](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.2/examples/accordion/accordion.html)

#### Example 2: height checking on click

```js
// add click event handlers
const selectorPanel = '.panel';
const selectorTrigger = '.acc-trigger';
const selectorAccContent = '.acc-body';
let accTriggers = document.querySelectorAll(selectorTrigger);
let accordionContents = document.querySelectorAll(selectorAccContent);
let panels = document.querySelectorAll(selectorPanel);

// add aria attributes
autoAriaAttributes(panels);
function autoAriaAttributes(panels){
    panels.forEach(function (panel, i) {
        let trigger = panel.querySelector(selectorTrigger);
        let acc = panel.querySelector(selectorAccContent);
        trigger.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
        if(!trigger.id){
            trigger.id = 'accTrigger-'+i;
        }
        trigger.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
        acc.setAttribute('aria-labelledby', trigger.id );
        acc.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true' );
    });
}

accTriggers.forEach(function (btn, i) {
    btn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        let panel = e.currentTarget.closest(selectorPanel);
        let btn = panel.querySelector(selectorTrigger);
        let acc = panel.querySelector(selectorAccContent);

        let opened = document.querySelectorAll('.active');
        // toggle this btn state
        panel.classList.toggle('active');
        let accHeight = acc.scrollHeight * 1.5;

        // apply max-height from data-attribute
        if (panel.classList.contains('active')) {
            acc.style.maxHeight = accHeight+'px';
            btn.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'true');
            acc.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'false');

        }else{
            acc.style.maxHeight = null;
            btn.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
            acc.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');
        }
        if(!isWideScreen() ){
            closeOpened(opened)
        }
    })
});

// add close all previously opened
function closeOpened(opened) {
        opened.forEach(function (panel, i) {
            let acc = panel.querySelector(selectorAccContent);
            let btn = panel.querySelector(selectorTrigger);
            panel.classList.remove('active');
            acc.style.maxHeight = null;
            btn.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
            acc.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');
        });
}

let isWideScreen = () => {
    return window.matchMedia("(min-width: 992px)").matches;
};

// recalculate heights on window resize
window.onresize = function(e) {
  let opened = document.querySelectorAll('.active');
  closeOpened(opened)
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 50px auto 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.wrapper a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.wrapper button {
  border-style: none;
  background: white;
}

.wrapper button::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
}

.wrapper .accordion:first-child {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.acc-trigger {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  outline: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: 0 0;
  padding: 1em 0;
}

.acc-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  color: inherit;
  pointer-events: none;
  margin-left: auto;
  z-index: 3;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  align-self: flex-start;
  padding: 0.5em 0;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.acc-trigger h4 {
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.acc-trigger:focus,
.acc-trigger:hover {
  color: #005fec;
}

.panel {
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000A70;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/**
* hidden acc body before initialisation to get heights 
* visibility is set to hidden 
* to prevent invisible elements from being focused
*/

.acc-body {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  max-height: 0px;
  transition-property: max-height, visibility;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-out;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
}

.active .acc-body {
  padding-bottom: 2em;
  visibility: visible;
  overflow: visible;
}

.acc-body p a {
  color: #005fec;
}

.acc-body p a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  -webkit-text-decoration-color: #005fec;
  text-decoration-color: #005fec;
}

.active .acc-icon {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.active .acc-trigger {
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}

.panel p:last-child {
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .wrapper {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .accordion {
    flex: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<style>
  body {
    font-size: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
  }
  
  .resizable {
    overflow: auto;
    resize: both;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 1em;
  }
  
  #questions {
    width: 800px;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
</style>

<!-- fallback if js disabled -->
<noscript>
        <style>
            .acc-body {
                padding-bottom: 2em;
                visibility: visible;
                overflow: visible;
                max-height:inherit;
            }
        </style>
</noscript>

<svg style="display:none" class="acc-icon" width="16" height="11" viewBox="0 0 16 11" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <symbol id="btn-acc" viewBox="0 0 16 11">
        <path d="M0 2.82813L2 0.828126L8 6.82813L14 0.828126L16 2.82813L8 10.8281L0 2.82813Z" fill="currentColor" />
    </symbol>
</svg>

<section class="resizable" id="questions">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="accordion">
            <div class="panel">
                <button class="acc-trigger">
                    <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h4>
                    <svg class="acc-icon" viewBox="0 0 16 11">
                        <use href="#btn-acc" />
                    </svg>
                </button>
                <div class="acc-body" style="color:#777">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="#">focusable link</a> consectetur adipisicing elit.
                        Animi enim quas laboriosam itaque harum ab voluptas? Deserunt aliquam pariatur voluptatem
                        odit iure autem eos totam eius consequuntur animi. Omnis, ipsam.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi enim quas laboriosam itaque
                        harum ab voluptas? Deserunt aliquam pariatur voluptatem odit iure autem eos totam eius
                        consequuntur animi. Omnis, ipsam.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi enim quas laboriosam itaque
                        harum ab voluptas? Deserunt aliquam pariatur voluptatem odit iure autem eos totam eius
                        consequuntur animi. Omnis, ipsam.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi enim quas laboriosam itaque
                        harum ab voluptas? Deserunt aliquam pariatur voluptatem odit iure autem eos totam eius
                        consequuntur animi. Omnis, ipsam. <strong>Last</strong></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel">
                <button class="acc-trigger">
                    <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. <br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </h4>
                    <svg class="acc-icon" viewBox="0 0 16 11">
                        <use href="#btn-acc" />
                    </svg>
                </button>
                <div class="acc-body">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi enim quas laboriosam itaque
                        harum ab voluptas? Deserunt aliquam pariatur voluptatem odit iure autem eos totam eius
                        consequuntur animi. Omnis, ipsam.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi enim quas laboriosam itaque
                        harum ab voluptas? Deserunt aliquam pariatur voluptatem odit iure autem eos totam eius
                        consequuntur animi. Omnis, ipsam.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi enim quas laboriosam itaque
                        harum ab voluptas? Deserunt aliquam pariatur voluptatem odit iure autem eos totam eius
                        consequuntur animi. Omnis, ipsam. <strong>Last</strong></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**Edits:**
To improve accessibility, collapsed accordion have visibility set to hidden to prevent hidden elements from getting focus (try to navigate via Tab key).
Basic ARIA attributes for visibility states can be added automatically.

This snippet will calculate the necessary max-height values on click via `element.scrollHeight`
Be careful: due to reflows this value might change after exapanding the accordion – therefore you might need some additional height like
`let accHeight = acc.scrollHeight * 1.5`;

There is also a "no-js" fallback to ensure all content is displayed, when js is disabled.

Comment: You removed a key feature that I already had written into my original script... On screens larger that 992px, multiple panels can be opened at once. Smaller screens would only allow for one panel at a time.

Comment: The panels in your snippet are also a bit jumpy. There's a delay in their opening.

Comment: @Millhorn: the viewPort check is back again (multiplae expanded accordions on larger devices).  The bumpy transition was caused by the additional p margin in collapsed state. You could rather add some additional bottom padding to the accordion body when expanded.

Comment: Last question I have for you... The function `getAccordionHeights()` is causing issues. Specifically, `accordion.setAttribute('data-height', (hh * 1.5) + 'px');` because some of my content is bigger or lengthier. It's only taking the `getBoundingClientRect()` method and multiplying that value times 1.5. Sometimes it's not enough. Is there a way to get any value? On many of my panels, the content is being cut off because the panel doesn't open enough.

Comment: @Millhorn: pardon me, I forgot: the parent .panel element needs to have  `position: relative` – otherwise the accordion content will have exceed the panel's boundaries. That's why you got smaller max-height values. So just add this one additional line and it should be working fine.

Comment: You rock. You definitely earned this! Thank you!

Comment: @Millhorn: tweaked some issues. E.g. you shouldn't be able to focus hidden elements. See the second snippet.

Comment: It's interesting because we found the same accessibility issue during a code review. I had already fixed it. Glad you caught it, too.

Comment: I'm wondering why you removed the `window.onresize` function? I'm having issues with that now and wondering if there's a reason why it was removed?

Comment: @Millhorn: the point of the second example was to calculate the necessary max-width on click event (reducing css layout complexity and dependencies like relative panel elements with absolute accordion contents) ... and to avoid unnecessary event handlers. Actually you could combine both approaches. What are those issues (e.g cropped contents)?

Comment: When I run your snippet, and resize the window, all the panels don't close, as I would expect them to. In my version, I've removed the `onresize` event and now when it resizes, the panels all remain open. Will a user resize their viewport? No... not likely, but they might go from landscape > portrait, and vice versa. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Millhorn: no big deal – you just have to add the resize handler once again (see revised snippet): the height checking helper is now obsolete. Besides, the viewport width check has moved to the click handler. The first example code is also revised to fix the previous focus issues.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to keep your behaviour like the one allowing to open multiple panel in wide screen. Also keep html untouched as requested and tried to modify css the less I can. I came up with following solution:

```js
const isWideScreen = () => {
  return window.matchMedia("(min-width: 992px)").matches;
};

const getPanelBody = (panel) => panel.querySelector(":scope > .acc-body");

const open = (panel) => {
  panel.classList.add("active");
  const panelBody = getPanelBody(panel);
  const tmpNode = panelBody.cloneNode(true);
  tmpNode.style.height = "auto";
  tmpNode.style.position = "absolute";
  tmpNode.style.visibility = "hidden";
  panel.insertBefore(tmpNode, panelBody);
  panelBody.style.height = tmpNode.scrollHeight + "px";
  tmpNode.remove();
};

const close = (panel) => {
  const panelBody = getPanelBody(panel);
  panel.classList.remove("active");
  panelBody.style.removeProperty("height");
};

function initAccordion(accordion) {
  const togglePanelHandler = (evt) => {
    const panel = evt.currentTarget.parentNode;
    const isWide = isWideScreen();
    const isActive = panel.classList.contains("active");
    // close other panels if ! isWide
    if (!isWide) {
      accordion.querySelectorAll(":scope > .panel.active").forEach(close);
    }
    if (!isActive) {
      open(panel);
    } else {
      close(panel);
    }
  };
  const triggers = accordion.querySelectorAll(":scope > .panel > .acc-trigger");
  // bind event handlers to trigggers that belong to that panel only
  triggers.forEach((trigger) =>
    trigger.addEventListener("click", togglePanelHandler)
  );
}

function initAccordions() {
  document.querySelectorAll(".accordion").forEach(initAccordion);
}

initAccordions();
```

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 50px auto 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.wrapper a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.wrapper button {
  border-style: none;
  background: white;
}
.wrapper button::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
}
.wrapper .accordion:first-child {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel {
  min-height: unset;
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000a70;
  transition: height 1s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-trigger {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: 0 0;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-trigger .acc-title {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  outline: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-trigger .acc-title:hover svg.acc-icon path {
  fill: #005fec;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-trigger .acc-title h4 {
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #000a70;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  outline: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-trigger .acc-title h4:hover {
  color: #005fec;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-trigger .acc-title svg.acc-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: none;
  margin-left: auto;
  z-index: 3;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-body {
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 1s ease-out, opacity 1s ease-out;
}

.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-body ol.custom-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-margin-before: 0;
  margin-block-start: 0;
  -webkit-margin-after: 0;
  margin-block-end: 0;
  counter-reset: my-awesome-counter;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-body ol.custom-list li {
  counter-increment: my-awesome-counter;
  padding-left: 1.125rem;
  margin: 2rem 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  color: #000a70;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-body ol.custom-list li::before {
  content: counter(my-awesome-counter) ". ";
  color: #005fec;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-body ol.custom-list li:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-body ol.custom-list li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-body ol.custom-list li a {
  color: #005fec;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-body ol.custom-list li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  -webkit-text-decoration-color: #005fec;
  text-decoration-color: #005fec;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-body ul.custom-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-margin-before: 0;
  margin-block-start: 0;
  -webkit-margin-after: 0;
  margin-block-end: 0;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-body ul.custom-list li {
  background-image: url(/assets/svg/bullet.svg);
  background-position: 0 0.5rem;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-left: 1.125rem;
  margin: 2rem 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-body ul.custom-list li a {
  color: #005fec;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-body ul.custom-list li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  -webkit-text-decoration-color: #005fec;
  text-decoration-color: #005fec;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-body ul.custom-list li:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-body ul.custom-list li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel + .panel {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel.active .acc-body {
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  visibility: visible;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel.active .acc-body p {
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel.active .acc-body p + .embed-youtube {
  margin: 1rem 0;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel.active .acc-body p a {
  color: #005fec;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel.active .acc-body p a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  -webkit-text-decoration-color: #005fec;
  text-decoration-color: #005fec;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel.active .acc-icon {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel.active .acc-trigger .acc-title {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel.active p:last-child {
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.acc-title svg.acc-icon {
  transition: all 1s ease;
  min-width: 1rem;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .wrapper {
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  .accordion {
    flex: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="questions">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-start">
      <h3>Any Questions?</h3>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="accordion">
          <div class="panel">
            <button class="acc-trigger">
              <span class="acc-title">
                <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h4>
                <svg
                  class="acc-icon"
                  width="16"
                  height="11"
                  viewBox="0 0 16 11"
                  fill="none"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                >
                  <path
                    d="M0 2.82813L2 0.828126L8 6.82813L14 0.828126L16 2.82813L8 10.8281L0 2.82813Z"
                    fill="#000A70"
                  />
                </svg>
              </span>
            </button>
            <div class="acc-body">
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi
                enim quas laboriosam itaque harum ab voluptas? Deserunt aliquam
                pariatur voluptatem odit iure autem eos totam eius consequuntur
                animi. Omnis, ipsam.
              </p>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi
                enim quas laboriosam itaque harum ab voluptas? Deserunt aliquam
                pariatur voluptatem odit iure autem eos totam eius consequuntur
                animi. Omnis, ipsam.
              </p>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi
                enim quas laboriosam itaque harum ab voluptas? Deserunt aliquam
                pariatur voluptatem odit iure autem eos totam eius consequuntur
                animi. Omnis, ipsam.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel">
            <button class="acc-trigger">
              <span class="acc-title">
                <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h4>
                <svg
                  class="acc-icon"
                  width="16"
                  height="11"
                  viewBox="0 0 16 11"
                  fill="none"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                >
                  <path
                    d="M0 2.82813L2 0.828126L8 6.82813L14 0.828126L16 2.82813L8 10.8281L0 2.82813Z"
                    fill="#000A70"
                  />
                </svg>
              </span>
            </button>
            <div class="acc-body">
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi
                enim quas laboriosam itaque harum ab voluptas? Deserunt aliquam
                pariatur voluptatem odit iure autem eos totam eius consequuntur
                animi. Omnis, ipsam.
              </p>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi
                enim quas laboriosam itaque harum ab voluptas? Deserunt aliquam
                pariatur voluptatem odit iure autem eos totam eius consequuntur
                animi. Omnis, ipsam.
              </p>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi
                enim quas laboriosam itaque harum ab voluptas? Deserunt aliquam
                pariatur voluptatem odit iure autem eos totam eius consequuntur
                animi. Omnis, ipsam.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Basically you can just replace your js file with the one above and change only the following css rules:

```
.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-body {
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* visibility: hidden; removed to see content transition on collapse*/
  transition: height 1s ease-out, opacity 1s ease-out;
}
.wrapper .accordion .panel.active .acc-body {
  opacity: 1;
  /* height: auto; removed as it will disallow transition on insertion */
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

I imagine you inherited that codebase, and are conscient that there's cleanup to do. Nevertheless I hope this will help a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Remove transitions from css?

```
.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-body {}
```

Comment: I need transitions, but I need the slide toggle transition at a certain speed.

Comment: try keyframes animations instead of just transformations.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp

Answer (score 0):

I've modified JS & CSS a bit so that the mobile height issue can be fixed. So when you're in smaller devices, you need to set the height to 0.

Also, you're setting the height to the entire panel, so the animation is weird, in this case, you can set the height to panel body. But the panel body is hidden, you need to add clone temporary fake element and get the height of the fake element which will later be removed from the DOM.

However, you can get a better version of vanilla accordion here: https://jsbin.com/juvobimavu/2/edit?html,css,js,output

But If you want to stick with your version, here is the snippet:

```js
function getElementHeight(el) {
  var clone = el.cloneNode(true);
  var width = el.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  clone.style.cssText =
    'position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; overflow: auto; visibility: hidden; pointer-events: none; height: unset; max-height: unset; width: ' +
    width +
    'px';
  document.body.append(clone);
  var height = clone.getBoundingClientRect().height + 'px';
  clone.remove();
  return height;
}

function initAccordion() {
  let handlePanelClick = (e) => {
    showPanel(e.currentTarget.parentNode);
  };

  function showPanel(panel) {
    let isWide = isWideScreen();
    let isActive = panel.classList.contains('active');

    if (!isActive) {
      panel.classList.add('active');
      panel.querySelector('.acc-body').style.height = '0';

      var height = getElementHeight(panel.querySelector('.acc-body'));

      panel.querySelector('.acc-body').style.height = '0px';

      setTimeout(() => {
        panel.querySelector('.acc-body').style.height = height;
      }, 0);
    } else {
      panel.querySelector('.acc-body').style.height = '0';

      panel.addEventListener(
        'transitionend',
        () => {
          panel.classList.remove('active');
        },
        {
          once: true,
        }
      );
    }

    if (isWide) {
      if (!isActive) {
        panel.classList.add('active');
      } else {
        panel.querySelector('.acc-body').style.height = '0';

        panel.addEventListener(
          'transitionend',
          () => {
            panel.classList.remove('active');
          },
          {
            once: true,
          }
        );
      }
    } else {
      // handle mobiles
      let panels = document.querySelectorAll('.panel');
      panels.forEach((p) => {
        p.classList.remove('active');
        p.querySelector('.acc-body').style.height = '0';
      });

      if (!isActive) {
        // open the panel
        panel.classList.add('active');
      }
    }
  }

  let allPanelElements = document.querySelectorAll('.panel');
  allPanelElements.forEach((allPanels) =>
    allPanels
      .querySelector('.acc-trigger')
      .addEventListener('click', handlePanelClick)
  );
}

let isWideScreen = () => {
  return window.matchMedia('(min-width: 992px)').matches;
};
initAccordion(document.getElementsByClassName('accordion'));
```

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 50px auto 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.wrapper a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.wrapper button {
  border-style: none;
  background: white;
}

.wrapper button::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
}

.wrapper .accordion:first-child {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.wrapper .accordion .panel {
  min-height: unset;
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000a70;
  transition: height 1s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-trigger {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: 0 0;
}

.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-trigger .acc-title {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  outline: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-trigger .acc-title:hover svg.acc-icon path {
  fill: #005fec;
}

.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-trigger .acc-title h4 {
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #000a70;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  outline: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-trigger .acc-title h4:hover {
  color: #005fec;
}

.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-trigger .acc-title svg.acc-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: none;
  margin-left: auto;
  z-index: 3;
}

.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-body {
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: height 1s ease-out, opacity 1s ease-out;
}

.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-body ol.custom-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-margin-before: 0;
  margin-block-start: 0;
  -webkit-margin-after: 0;
  margin-block-end: 0;
  counter-reset: my-awesome-counter;
}

.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-body ol.custom-list li {
  counter-increment: my-awesome-counter;
  padding-left: 1.125rem;
  margin: 2rem 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  color: #000a70;
}

.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-body ol.custom-list li::before {
  content: counter(my-awesome-counter) '. ';
  color: #005fec;
}

.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-body ol.custom-list li:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-body ol.custom-list li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-body ol.custom-list li a {
  color: #005fec;
}

.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-body ol.custom-list li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  -webkit-text-decoration-color: #005fec;
  text-decoration-color: #005fec;
}

.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-body ul.custom-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-margin-before: 0;
  margin-block-start: 0;
  -webkit-margin-after: 0;
  margin-block-end: 0;
}

.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-body ul.custom-list li {
  background-image: url(/assets/svg/bullet.svg);
  background-position: 0 0.5rem;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-left: 1.125rem;
  margin: 2rem 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}

.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-body ul.custom-list li a {
  color: #005fec;
}

.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-body ul.custom-list li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  -webkit-text-decoration-color: #005fec;
  text-decoration-color: #005fec;
}

.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-body ul.custom-list li:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.wrapper .accordion .panel .acc-body ul.custom-list li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.wrapper .accordion .panel + .panel {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.wrapper .accordion .panel.active .acc-body {
  opacity: 1;
  height: auto;
  /* padding: 0.5rem 0; */
  margin: 0.5rem 0;
  visibility: visible;
}

.wrapper .accordion .panel.active .acc-body p {
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}

.wrapper .accordion .panel.active .acc-body p + .embed-youtube {
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.wrapper .accordion .panel.active .acc-body p a {
  color: #005fec;
}

.wrapper .accordion .panel.active .acc-body p a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  -webkit-text-decoration-color: #005fec;
  text-decoration-color: #005fec;
}

.wrapper .accordion .panel.active .acc-icon {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.wrapper .accordion .panel.active .acc-trigger .acc-title {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.wrapper .accordion .panel.active p:last-child {
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.acc-title svg.acc-icon {
  transition: all 1s ease;
  min-width: 1rem;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .wrapper {
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  .accordion {
    flex: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="questions">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-start">
        <h3>Any Questions?</h3>
        <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="accordion">
            <div class="panel">
            <button class="acc-trigger">
                <span class="acc-title">
                <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h4>
                <svg
                    class="acc-icon"
                    width="16"
                    height="11"
                    viewBox="0 0 16 11"
                    fill="none"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                >
                    <path
                    d="M0 2.82813L2 0.828126L8 6.82813L14 0.828126L16 2.82813L8 10.8281L0 2.82813Z"
                    fill="#000A70"
                    />
                </svg>
                </span>
            </button>
            <div class="acc-body">
                <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                Animi enim quas laboriosam itaque harum ab voluptas?
                Deserunt aliquam pariatur voluptatem odit iure autem eos
                totam eius consequuntur animi. Omnis, ipsam.
                </p>
                <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                Animi enim quas laboriosam itaque harum ab voluptas?
                Deserunt aliquam pariatur voluptatem odit iure autem eos
                totam eius consequuntur animi. Omnis, ipsam.
                </p>
                <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                Animi enim quas laboriosam itaque harum ab voluptas?
                Deserunt aliquam pariatur voluptatem odit iure autem eos
                totam eius consequuntur animi. Omnis, ipsam.
                </p>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel">
            <button class="acc-trigger">
                <span class="acc-title">
                <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h4>
                <svg
                    class="acc-icon"
                    width="16"
                    height="11"
                    viewBox="0 0 16 11"
                    fill="none"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                >
                    <path
                    d="M0 2.82813L2 0.828126L8 6.82813L14 0.828126L16 2.82813L8 10.8281L0 2.82813Z"
                    fill="#000A70"
                    />
                </svg>
                </span>
            </button>
            <div class="acc-body">
                <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                Animi enim quas laboriosam itaque harum ab voluptas?
                Deserunt aliquam pariatur voluptatem odit iure autem eos
                totam eius consequuntur animi. Omnis, ipsam.
                </p>
                <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                Animi enim quas laboriosam itaque harum ab voluptas?
                Deserunt aliquam pariatur voluptatem odit iure autem eos
                totam eius consequuntur animi. Omnis, ipsam.
                </p>
                <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                Animi enim quas laboriosam itaque harum ab voluptas?
                Deserunt aliquam pariatur voluptatem odit iure autem eos
                totam eius consequuntur animi. Omnis, ipsam.
                </p>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</section>
```